# Tensorflow 2.0 not installing on pipenv with Heroku

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the pipenv lock working for django with tf, but it won't proceed to install on the heroku server.

```
An error occurred while installing tensorflow==2.0.0! Will try again.
```

I'm wishing the server could have 2.0 tensorflow installed, but it fails and there's no prior help.

```
dj-database-url = "==0.5.0"
django-storages = "==1.7.1"
django = "==2.1.5"
gunicorn = "==19.9.0"
psycopg2-binary = "==2.7.6.1"
psycopg2 = "==2.7.6.1"
markdownify = "==0.4.1"
numpy = "==1.16.2"
pipenv = "*"
regex = "==2017.4.5"
tensorboard = "*"
tb-nightly = "==1.14.0a20190301"
tf-estimator-nightly = "==1.14.0.dev2019030115"
tensorflow = "*"
tensorflow-estimator = "*"
Keras-Applications = "*"
Keras-Preprocessing = "*"
```

The local machine installs tensorflow to 2.0.0
But the heroku machine needs 2.0.0a0 or b0 or b1, which won't install locally.

`pipenv install tensorflow -v` brings up:

```
requires absl-py>=0.7.0, astor>=0.6.0, gast==0.2.2, google-pasta>=0.1.6, grpcio>=1.8.6, keras-applications>=1.0.8, keras-preprocessing>=1.0.5, numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0, opt-einsum>=2.3.2, protobuf>=3.6.1, six>=1.10.0, tensorboard<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, tensorflow-estimator<2.1.0,>=2.0.0, termcolor>=1.1.0, wheel>=0.26, wrapt>=1.11.1
```

This fits with the installed packages, but is set to 2.0.0, not a0, b0, or b1.

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.0.0 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-0_4yw8_o-requirements/pipenv-d2wfuv4u-requirement.txt (line 1)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
```

The required packages are:

```
absl-py = "==0.7.1"
astor = "==0.7.1"
gast = "==0.2.2"
protobuf = "*"
six = "==1.12.0"
termcolor = "==1.1.0"
```

Comment: Try increasing pipenv verbosity (`-v`) while installing if you don't see any error yet.

Comment: is that `pipenv lock -v` or `pipenv install tensorflow -v`?

Comment: `pipenv --help` gives `Usage: pipenv [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...`, so I'd try `pipenv -v install`, which `(if no packages are given), installs all packages from Pipfile.`

Comment: neither option worked

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow only supports from python 3.4 up to python 3.7 (as March 2020). You can find more info in the [system requirements page][1] of the documentation.

Make sure that in your Pipfile you have the following:

```
[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

If that is not the case, remove the virtual environment, change the `python_version` to the correct one and recreate the environment.

I hope it helps!